# How to insert declared type variable into table | Postgress

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have been working on creating a store procedure that will select data from a table, do some modification to that data, and then I need to insert that modified data into the same table. Take an example my table name is `student`. My procedure looks like below:

```
create or replace procedure student_create(p_code varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   v_student public.student;
begin
    select * into v_student from student where code = p_code and is_latest_version is true;
    raise notice 'Value: %', v_student;
    v_student.id = uuid_generate_v4();
    v_student.version_created_at = now();
    v_student.version_updated_at = v_student.version_created_at;
    raise notice 'Value: %', v_student;
    INSERT INTO public.student VALUES(v_student);
end;$$
```

I am getting errors while calling this procedure:

```
ERROR:  column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type hotel
LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.hotel VALUES(v_hotel)
```

I know I can make insert statements like I can get each value from the variable and set it like

```
INSERT INTO public.student VALUES(v_student.id, v_student.code, v_student.name);
```

But I don't want to do that because it will become tightly coupled and later if I add another column into the table then I need to add that column into this procedure as well.

Does anyone have idea how can I insert the declared type variable directly into table.

Comment: Have you tried `v_student.*`? Also why not just do as `DEFAULTS`  on the relevant columns?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver So basically this procedure is used to copy existing data and make a new copy. So don't thik the defaults will work here

Comment: Just noticed your error is for different code, `INSERT INTO public.hotel VALUES(v_hotel)`. Is this a copy and paste mistake or is there more to the procedure?

Comment: Can you show public.student table definition?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-insert.html The Compatibility section:     
> Also, the case in which a column name list is omitted, but not all the columns are filled  from the VALUES clause or query, is disallowed by the standard.          
so `INSERT INTO public.student VALUES(v_student.id, v_student.code, v_student.name);` IS Wrong.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, your idea of making it `v_student.*` worked for me and that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no table type, there is only row composite type. Check manual **43.3.4. Row Types**.
2. use row type.

---

```
create or replace procedure student_create(p_code text)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   v_student public.student
begin
    for v_student in  select *  from student where code = p_code and is_latest_version is true
    loop
    v_student.id = uuid_generate_v4();
    v_student.version_created_at = now();
    v_student.version_updated_at = v_student.version_created_at;
    v_student.is_latest_version = true;
    v_student.code = p_code;
    INSERT INTO student VALUES(v_student.*);
end loop;
end;$$;
```

call it: `call student_create('hello');`
3. use `update` clause directly.

```
create or replace procedure student_create_1(p_code text)
language plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
    with a  as ( select uuid_generate_v4() as id ,
                       now() as version_created_at,
                       now() as version_updated_at,
                       p_code as "code"   from student 
                where code = p_code and is_latest_version is true)
    
     INSERT INTO student(id, version_created_at, version_updated_at, code) 
            select a.id, a.version_created_at,a.version_updated_at,a."code" from a;
    
end
$$;
```

call it: `call student_create_1('hello');`

fiddle code: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bbd295f6b313e15f8def201f74d0ffbd)

Comment: 1) You don't have to use `%rowtype` per [Row Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES): "(Since every table has an associated composite type of the same name, it actually does not matter in PostgreSQL whether you write %ROWTYPE or not. But the form with %ROWTYPE is more portable.)" 2) The OP did not want to have to specify individual columns in the `VALUES()` and indicated in their post they knew that would work.

Comment: Except the part where the OP was already using a row type as `v_student public.student;` = `v_student student%rowtype;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver updated.  I know table have associated composite type, just don't know how to use it. Now I know. thanks.

Comment: @Mark 3. will only insert those columns, I have a lot of columns that I don't want to change and copy as the new records. So I don't think it solves my issue

Comment: @DeepakKumar. You already declared `v_student public.student;` table composite type, you either explicitly partial insert. `insert student(cola, colb) values(a, b)`  or  full insert : `insert students values(all the columns)`.

Comment: @DeepakKumar and you cannot do `INSERT INTO public.student VALUES(v_student.id, v_student.code, v_student.name);` because you table  obviously more than 3 column. You need `INSERT INTO public.student(id, code, name) VALUES(v_student.id, v_student.code). 
 v_student.name);`  If you want more dynamic check manual 38.2.5 section Polymorphic type.