# insert function with side-effects: how to take insert parameter?

Tags: postgresql

I'm interested in writing a Postgres function that inserts a new row to e.g. an `invoice` table, and performs some side effects based on the result of the insertion. My `invoice` table has some columns with default values (e.g. auto-generated primary key column `id`), and some that are optional.

I'm wondering if there's a way to take a parameter that represents a row of the `invoice` table, possibly without default and optional fields, and insert that value directly as a row.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_invoice(new_invoice invoice)
RETURNS uuid
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
WITH invoice_insert_result AS (
    -- This fails: new_invoice has type invoice, but expected type uuid (because it thinks we want to put `new_invoice` in the "id" column)
    INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (new_invoice)
    RETURNING id
) 
-- Use the result to perform side-effects
SELECT invoice_insert_result.id
$$;
```

I know this is possible to do by replicating the schema of the `invoice` table in the list of parameters of the function, however I'd prefer not to do that since it would mean additional boilerplate and maintenance burden.

Comment: Why not just create an `INSERT` trigger on the table `invoice` and modify the `NEW` fields as needed? See [Trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

- The uuid is a value that is automatically generated, you cannot insert a uuid value to a table.
- 

> The target column names can be listed in any order. If no list of
> column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the
> table in their declared order; or the first N column names, if there
> are only N columns supplied by the VALUES clause or query. The values
> supplied by the VALUES clause or query are associated with the
> explicit or implicit column list left-to-right.
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

The quote part means that you insert command can either explicit mention ***column list***. Or you not mention ***column list*** then the to be inserted command (after *values*) should have all the column list's value.

to achiever your intended result, Insert command,you must specify **columns list.** If not, then you need insert uuid value. But you cannot uuid is auto generated. The same example would be like if a table have a column bigserial then you cannot insert bigserial value to that column. Since bigserial is auto-generated.

For other non-automatic column, You can aggregated them use customized type.
denmo

```
create type inv_insert_template as (receiver text, base_amount numeric,tax_rate numeric);
```

full function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_invoice(new_invoice inv_insert_template)
RETURNS bigint
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
WITH invoice_insert_result AS (
    INSERT INTO invoices(receiver,base_amount, tax_rate)
        VALUES (new_invoice.receiver,
                new_invoice.base_amount,
                new_invoice.tax_rate) RETURNING inv_no
)
SELECT invoice_insert_result.inv_no from invoice_insert_result;
$$;
```

call it: `select * from public.insert_invoice(row('person_c', 1000, 0.1));`
[db fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=63f46a6a03abc34e3771183fd73711ef)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458498/how-to-insert-declared-type-variable-into-table-postgress/71467610#71467610